# raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e)) kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

minimal django/celery/redis is running locally, but when deployed to heroku gives me the following error, when I run on python:

```
 raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
 kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection     
 refused.
```

This is my tasks.py file in my application directory:

```
   from celery import Celery
   import os

   app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

   app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
            CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])

   @app.task
   def add(x, y):
      return x + y
```

Requirements.txt:

```
  django
  gunicorn
  django-heroku
  celery
  redis
  celery-with-redis
  django-celery
  kombu
```

I have set worker dyno to 1.
Funny things is i could have sworn it was working before, now it doesnt work for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me, i forgot to import celery in project/**init**.py  like so

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once, you have a [minimal django-celery-redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58884219/clarification-of-guide-to-heroku-celery) project setup on local, here is how you deploy it on heroku:

1. Add to your tasks.py:

   ```
    import os

    app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
       CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
   ```
2. Make sure your requirements.txt is like this:

   ```
    django
    gunicorn
    django-heroku
    celery
    redis
   ```
3. Add to your Procfile: "worker: celery worker --app=hello.tasks.app"
4. Make sure it still runs on local
5. enter into terminal: "export REDIS_URL=redis://"
6. run "heroku local&"
7. run python

   ```
    import hello.tasks
    hello.tasks.add.delay(1,2)
   ```

Should return something like:

```
    <AsyncResult: e1debb39-b61c-47bc-bda3-ee037d34a6c4>
```

7. "heroku apps:create minimal-django-celery-redis"
8. "heroku addons:create heroku-redis -a minimal-django-celery-redis"
9. "git add ."
10. "git commit -m "Demo""
11. "git push heroku master"
12. "heroku open&"
13. "heroku ps:scale worker=1"
14. "heroku run python"

    ```
      import hello.tasks
      hello.tasks.add.delay(1, 2)
    ```
15. You should see the task running in the application logs: "heroku logs -t -p worker"